# Angular Formio form validation with "required" property not working

Tags: angular, forms, frontend, formio

I am working on an Angular project that uses Formio to render dynamic forms. In my form, I have some fields that are marked as required by setting the `required` property to `true` in the JSON definition. However, when I submit the form, the validation doesn't seem to be working properly, as the form can still be submitted even if required fields are left blank.

Here is an example of one of the fields in the JSON definition:

```
"validate": {
  "json": "",
  "custom": "",
  "unique": false,
  "pattern": "",
  "multiple": false,
  "required": true,
  "maxLength": "",
  "minLength": "",
  "customMessage": "",
  "customPrivate": false,
  "strictDateValidation": false
},
```

This is in the component html:

```
   <div *ngIf="form && submission">
        <formio [form]="form"
                [submission]="submission"
                [readOnly]="readonly"
                [viewOnly]="readonly">
        </formio>
    </div>
```

I tried to create a custom validation, but it's overkill because the user will put the required validation for whatever component of formio and fields he wants.

Comment: How is the application behaving when you submit the form? I'm able just now to spin up a simple form and prevent submission by using the `required` JSON parameter, can you give some more details?

Comment: @BrendanBond even with the required set to true in the JSON the app let's me submit the form. The problem i think it's that it doesn't automatically set the required attribute for the given HTML element like input, select etc.

Comment: I understand that you're having trouble, but I think some more information would be helpful. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-goldberg-v926zl?file=/src/app/app.module.ts) is a simple angular application that embeds a Form.io form with  a required field, I can't submit it until I fill the required field. Can you provide a similar [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can help point you in the right direction?